# How to get size depends on some conditions in aggregate of MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have some data as below in MongoDB:

```
{
  date: [
    {
      "updatedAt": "2020-10-01T12:12:12Z"
    },
    {
      "updatedAt": "2020-10-01T12:12:12Z"
    },
    {
      "updatedAt": "2020-10-01T12:12:12Z"
    },
    {
      "updatedAt": null
    },
    {
      "updatedAt": "2020-10-01T12:12:12Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to get a size of some condition that has

1. The size is the length of a group which has not `null`.
2. But first, and last elements has not to counted for this.

So In this case not null data size is "2" except first and last element.
I want to get this size in an aggregate of MongoDb.
I can make this projecting only `updatedAt` in the aggregate as below.

```
{
  $project: {
    "date.updatedAt": 1
  }
}
 
// some for loop logic outside of the aggregate
```

However, I don't want to for loop here. Is it possible this size only inside of the aggregate?
Can you some advice for this query? Thank you so much for reading it.

Comment: If the array is length 1, do you expect result to be 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try,

- `$reduce` to iterate loop of `date` array, after removing first and last element using `$slice`, `$size` to get size of array, `$subtract` to remove
- `$cond` check if `updatedAt` not null then `$add` to value and return value

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      size: {
        $reduce: {
          input: {
            $slice: [
              "$date",
              1,
              { $subtract: [{ $size: "$date" }, 2] }
            ]
          },
          initialValue: 0,
          in: {
            $add: [
              "$$value",
              { $cond: [{ $ne: ["$$this.updatedAt", null] }, 1, 0] }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OZwTN5DFS6R)

---

Second approach using `$filter`

- `$filter` to iterate loop of `date` array, after removing first and last element using `$slice`, `$size` to get size of array, `$subtract` to remove
- cond check if `updatedAt` not null and filter will return filtered array, `$size` to get total size of array returned from `$filter`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      a: {
        $size: {
          $filter: {
            input: {
              $slice: [
                "$date",
                1,
                { $subtract: [{ $size: "$date" }, 2] }
              ]
            },
            cond: { $ne: ["$$this.updatedAt", null] }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/iGYOQO60xj_)